# My overseas girlfriend are not using her own passport but we need to get married? so how?

Tags: visa, immigration, passport

This is a serious problem and quite a long story but here goes.

About 6-7 years ago, my girlfriend (from indonesia) come to malaysia(my place) with a social visit pass but work here illegally. She came here with her ex husband. Before departing to Malaysia, her agent gave her passport to her which does not contain her details(name, date of birth, etc.), it is someone else information. To make it short, it is not her passport but contain her fingerprint details in it. Despite the conflict, she departed to malaysia anyway with her ex husband. 4 years later(she was already divorced at this time), she made a work permit which allow her to work at malaysia and the permit need to be renewed every year. Thats when we met. But her boss is holding her permit and passport for some unknown reason, which make it difficult for us to meet each another and doing fun things like watching movie, going to the park and such. so i ask her to stop renewing her work permit and go back to indonesia and return here with a normal social visit instead so we can get married.

Now this is the part where it stresses me, her passport is almost expired so she get it renewed but she were not allowed to change the information on the passport. So the passport got renewed for another 5 years with the same information. Since we want to get married, i need to register her properly as my wife-to-be at the malaysias custom, etc. before we can arrange a proper marriage. i was born in 1991 and she was born in 1992. But her passport says, she was born in 1986. That is way older. Not to mention, the wrong name, address, and so on.

as for a direct question, is there a way to dump her current passport and create a new passport with the correct details? it is very urgent. please help me. at least direct me to something which can lead me to an answer.

Comment: It sounds like she needs to abandon the fake identity and get a legit Indonesian passport.  If Malaysia checks fingerprints, though, you're basically stuck.

Comment: Be careful, this whole story sounds rather dodgy and might be worth checking out some more.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way around this could be to get married in Indonesia - that way she does not need a passport to prove her identity, but you do.

Then she could change her name to use yours (if she would like to do that), and apply for a passport with her new name and correct details.

Problems could arise because her biometric details would match her older bogus identity. Unfortunately, it is possible that the only way to make this problem go away might be the same way that the original identity was made, through the age-old tradition of government corruption.

(NOTE: I am not condoning bribery and corruption, but it would seem that that may be how the situation came about in the first place)